# How to echo an error in my page so that I can style it?

Tags: php, html

In my *php script*, I have a simple **username/ email exists** condition, but I want to put the error (should it exist) somewhere in my *html*, so that I can style it and position it over my form. Echo just puts it top-left. How can I do that? Setting a variable seems like *not* the optimal solution.

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST["register"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);

    $conflictUserQuery = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
    $conflictUserResult = mysqli_query($conn, $conflictUserQuery);
    $conflictUserRow = mysqli_fetch_array($conflictUserResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $conflictMailQuery = "SELECT email FROM members WHERE email='$email'";
    $conflictMailResult = mysqli_query($conn, $conflictMailQuery);
    $conflictMailRow = mysqli_fetch_array($conflictMailResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($conflictMailResult) ==1){
        echo "Could not be registered. Mail exists.";
    }
    elseif(mysqli_num_rows($conflictUserResult) ==1){
        echo "Could not be registered. Username exists.";
    }
    else{
        $registerQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')");
        if($registerQuery){
            echo "Thank You! you are now registered.";
        }
    }


}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-enable flex-center">
            <div class="flex-enable flex-center semiOverride flex-center px100">
                <div class="flex-enable flex-center flex-column">
                    <h2 class="big-white-title">Register.</h2>
                    <h3 class="medium-white-title">Be a part of this.</h3>
                <form class="flex-enable flex-center flex-column" method="POST">
                    <input class="form-input-text small-white-title" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                    <input class="form-input-text small-white-title" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <input class="form-input-text small-white-title" type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
                    <input class="form-button small-white-title" type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
                </form>
                <h3 class="small-white-subtitle">Or <a id="register" href="">login</a> if you have an account.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="attribution">Photo by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@meindrittesauge">Sebastian Kanczok</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Setting a variable seems like not the optimal solution." Why not? That's the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I'm a beginner in coding, and I thought setting variables should be avoided because they would bloat memory. I would have thought something along the lines of a goto() or something similar.

Comment: @mechanicarts may I suggest a few changes to your code. **Please never store plain text passwords!** It is unsafe and PHP provides these two special function to hash passwords: [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. Make sure you [**don't escape passwords**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/5914775) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding. (1/2)

Comment: And your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5914775). Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/5914775). Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. (2/2) Since you're a beginner these things are easily 'dismissed', but they provide you with the proper security to help you develop secure things in the future.

Comment: Did you mean something like this? `echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">Could not be registered. Mail exists.</span>";` - if not, can you elaborate on your post in more detail? @mechanicarts

Comment: I don't have to use any amount of security. I do get that it's not applicable in real-life scenarios, but it's an assignment and we're supposed to use only the basics, specifically for passwords we shouldn't care at all about encrypting them (someone did ask). Fred, no, I mean that I want to echo the error somewhere inside my page, outside the php script, specifically over my form.

Comment: @mechanicarts ok, well this could be is as simple as assigning a variable to it then `$error = "<span style=\"color:red;\">Error message here.</span>";` or use a stylesheet with an `.error` class and apply it to an error element and simply place the `$error` where you want it to appear and with an `isset()`.

Comment: Probably my solution! Can you write it in an answer so that we can close it?

Comment: @mechanicarts Got 'er down there ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in comments:

This could be is as simple as assigning a variable to it then, while using an inline CSS styling method:

```
$error = "<span style=\"color:red;\">Error message here.</span>";
```

You could also use a stylesheet with an `.error` class (that can be used for multiple instances as opposed to an `#id`) and apply it to an error element and simply place the `$error` variable where you would like it to appear and with an `isset()`.

Note: The use of [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is important since it will avoid a possible undefined variable notice.

You could also use a ternary operator:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

which also works quite well for something like this, since you could set a default message for it.

As noted in comments, it'd be better to use a prepared statement and using a safe password storing/hashing method is highly advised.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I was getting constant errors about undefined, then I saw your `isset()` addition. Works like a charm!

Comment: @mechanicarts Ahhhhh, and that's why I thought I'd add that to the answer earlier, just in case and to cover that base ;-) Glad to hear that you worked it all out, *cheers!* and you're most welcome.